# node.js Nan: call JavaScript callback in C++ function

Tags: javascript, c++, node.js, node.js-addon, node.js-nan

I’m building a node-module wrapper for a C++ library to pass logging information through [Nan](https://github.com/nodejs/nan) to JavaScript. For this a NAN_Method is available to register a callback. The callback handler has to register itself as a callback at the C++ library via `vlAddLogListener()`. The `LoggingCallbackHandler` receives a message from the library at the function `dispatchEvent`, a C++ function. If I receive a log, I want to call the JavaScript callback to pass the data on.

The function `dispatchEvent` isn’t called in a Nan-context and therefore I don’t have a scope/context and no access to v8. How is it possible to call the JavaScript callback?

The code looks like this:

```
NAN_METHOD(registerLoggingCallback) 
{
    v8::Isolate* isolate = info.GetIsolate();
    v8::Local<v8::Function> fun = info[0].As<v8::Function>();
    lch = new LoggingCallbackHandler(isolate, fun);
}

LoggingCallbackHandler::LoggingCallbackHandler(v8::Isolate* isolate, v8::Local<v8::Function> fun) :
    _cb(isolate, fun)
{
    vlAddLogListener(&LoggingCallbackHandler::dispatchEvent, this);
}

void VL_CALLINGCONVENTION LoggingCallbackHandler::dispatchEvent(const char* eventData, void* clientData)
{
    // here I want to process the data and call the JavaScript callback
    v8::Local<v8::Function> f = v8::Local<v8::Function>::New(Nan::GetCurrentContext()->Global()->GetIsolate(), _cb);
    Nan::MakeCallback(Nan::GetCurrentContext()->Global(), f, argc, argv);
}
```

Comment: Did you make it? Would be nice if you could provide your solution.

Answer (score 4):

Using `Nan`, you should save the function value using a `Nan::Callback` inside your `registerLoggingCallback` function :

```cpp
Nan::Callback cb;
cb.Reset(info[0].As<v8::Function>());
```

Store this `Nan::Callback` inside your class.  Modify your `dispatchEvent` function to use a `uv_async_t` to schedule a call to your callback to be run in the main thread.

The use of `uv_async_t` can be simplified using a `Nan::AsyncWorker` but you may be better off reading the [documentation](http://github.com/nodejs/nan/blob/master/doc/asyncworker.md) for a better understanding of how that works.

When you actually want to call the callback, you can do:

```cpp
v8::Local<v8::Value> arg = Nan::Null();
cb.Call(1, &arg);
```

You can pass more values into the callback by passing an array of `v8::Local<v8::Value>` as the second parameter and increasing the first parameter accordingly.